# Como guardar o versionamento de software com GIT?

Tags: git, arquivo, versionamento

Fiz o projeto, ta todo o versionamento no **GIT**, porém como eu posso fazer uma espécie de backup desses dados?

Por que vamos supor que eu formate o PC, salvei o projeto porém perdi o versionamento feito.

Pesquisei e disseram pra apenas salvar a pasta invisível `.git` também, mas não há outras maneiras se salvar o versionamento do projeto?

Comment: sim, o versionamento fica salvo na pasta `.git`. Dá pra salvar de várias formas, todas elas envolvem fazer uma cópia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para backup é só você compactar a pasta do repositório, inteira, e não somente o .git, daí é só restaurar, ou descompactar o backup, e sair usando.
Você pode também colocar no Dropbox, se tiver uma pasta sincronizada com o serviço, automaticamente, terá o backup.
Porém a melhor maneira é você ter um repositório remoto. E para isso você pode fazer uso de serviços como:

- [Github](https://github.com)
- [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com)
- [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)

Eles tem opções gratuitas de hospedagem do repositório, basta enviar o código pela linha de comando:

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o https://bitbucket.org/ para manter o seu "Backup"dos seus códigos fonte.

É só criar um repositório e commitar lá!

No Bitbucket tem todas as instruções necessárias.

Espero ter ajudado!